# Javascript for() loop & arr.push() optimization

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have an array that I want to change the format and keys, to achieve I have done some research on StackOverflow and still not achieve the desired result

**This is my array:**

```
  var data =  [{ 
   timestamp: '1434569340',
   close: '127.6100',
   high: '127.7600',
   low: '127.6050',
   open: '127.7200',
   volume: '337000' },
 { timestamp: '1434569641',
   close: '127.5700',
   high: '127.6701',
   low: '127.5100',
   open: '127.6100',
   volume: '328200' }];
```

**That is what I want to achieve:**

```
  var newData = [{
    "t" : [1434569340, 1434569641], //timestamp
    "c" : [127.6100, 127.5700], //close
    "h" : [127.7600, 127.6701], //high
    "l" : [127.6050, 127.5100], //low
    "o" : [127.7200, 127.6100 ], //open
    "v" : [337000, 328200] }]; //volume
```

Currently I am using the following code to get closer to the result (seen in other questions on StackOverflow):

```
var arr =[{}];
var len = data.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(
       data[i].timestamp  );
}

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(
       data[i].close  );
}
```

**Result the previous code:**

```
[Object, "1434569340", "1434569641", "1434569940", "1434570241", "127.6100", "127.5700", "127.5500", "127.4800", "127.7600", "127.6701", "127.6099"]
```

The code comes close to what I need but the method is quite obtuse, and should keep writing code to add keys, etc.
Clearly my knowledge of javascript are quite poor, and my question is how could achieve the desired result by optimizing the code.

**Thank you very much for your time, apologize for my English.**

Comment: Why use an array of a single object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional approach:

```
var newData = Object.keys(data[0]).reduce(function (res, key) {
    res[key[0]] = data.map(function (item) { return item[key]; });
    return res;
}, {});
```

Slightly shorter version using Underscore/lo-dash `pluck`:

```
var newData = Object.keys(data[0]).reduce(function (res, key) {
    res[key[0]] = _.pluck(data, key);
    return res;
}, {});
```

Comment: @Ja͢ck that's pretty obvious, if this your case you need to check for that separately.

Comment: I guess my hint wasn't obvious then, there's no need to check for that if you reduce `data` instead of `Object.keys(data[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function flip (arrOfObjs) {
  var objOfArrs = {}; // make the object to return
  arrOfObjs.forEach(function(obj){
    for(var key in obj) {
      objOfArrs[key] = objOfArrs[key] || []; // set the key to an array
      objOfArrs[key].push(obj[key]); // add the value for this key of this object to the array
    }
  });
  return objOfArrs;
}
```

Then you can do `var newData = [flip(data)]` and you'll get an array containing one object, each key being "timestamp", "close", "high" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```js
function makeNewData(a, b) { // args: 2 arrays with same keys
  var result = {};

  var key, new_key;
  for (key in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key) && b.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // check if both arrays have this key
      new_key = key.charAt(0); // new key will be the first char of old key
      result[new_key] = [a[key], b[key]]; // create array with 2 values
    }
  }

  return result;
}

var data = [{
  timestamp: '1434569340',
  close: '127.6100',
  high: '127.7600',
  low: '127.6050',
  open: '127.7200',
  volume: '337000'
}, {
  timestamp: '1434569641',
  close: '127.5700',
  high: '127.6701',
  low: '127.5100',
  open: '127.6100',
  volume: '328200'
}];

console.log(makeNewData(data[0], data[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic I can find is the following loop:

```
for( var i = 0, l = data.length; i<l; i++ )
{
    for(var k in data[i])
    {
        if( !(k[0] in newData) )
        {
            newData[k[0]] = [];
        }

        newData[k[0]].push( data[i][k] );
    }
}
```

This will create the required structure, but you should initialize the variables in the following way:

```
var data = [
        { 
            timestamp: '1434569340',
            close: '127.6100',
            high: '127.7600',
            low: '127.6050',
            open: '127.7200',
            volume: '337000'
        },
        {
            timestamp: '1434569641',
            close: '127.5700',
            high: '127.6701',
            low: '127.5100',
            open: '127.6100',
            volume: '328200'
        }
    ], newData = {};
```

It makes no sense to use an array to store a single object.

If that is a requirement, use the following loop:

```
for( var i = 0, l = data.length; i<l; i++ )
{
    for(var k in data[i])
    {
        if( !(k[0] in newData) )
        {
            newData[0][k[0]] = [];
        }

        newData[0][k[0]].push( data[i][k] );
    }
}
```